# Why cmp_function of usort needs so many restrictions?

Tags: php, sorting

Quoted from [here](http://cn.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or
>   greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be
>   respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

In my opinion, `cmp_function` needs only to return `1` if the first is greater than the second.

Why does it need all `3` cases ?

**UPDATE**

```
function bubble($list)
{
    $length = count($list) - 2;
    $sorted = false;

    while(!$sorted)
    {
        $sorted = true;
        foreach(range(0,$length) as $i)
        {
            if($list[$i] > $list[$i + 1])
            {
                $sorted = false;
                list($list[$i],$list[$i + 1]) = array($list[$i + 1],$list[$i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $list;
}
```

Comment: Then implement a new sort function based on your optinion. The implementer(s) of usort had other opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that it can distinguish between `<`, `==` and `>`.

This is similar to the requirements on the callback for e.g. C's `qsort` (for all I know, `usort` may be implemented using `qsort` internally).

It is possible to write a search routine that only needs a two-valued predicate, but `usort` happens not to be one of them.

Comment: Think of bubble sort, only `<` or `>` is enough.

Comment: @lexer: Because it gives the library authors more freedom, and it also means that functions like `strcmp` can be used very easily as the callback.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you're almost right, you don't need 3 differents values.

But, 1 single value isn't sufficient, you need 2 values:

- 1(true) <=> first > second
- 0(false) <=> first <= second

Comment: @Luis in fact you're really wrong; it's possible, with 1 <=> ">" and 0 <=> "<=" to build a sorting that doesn't even do unnecessary swaps; it's a little bit unnatural but it's perfectly possible to sort using ">" instead of "<"

Comment: Simone, I am sorry, you are write, 0 or any negative value in fact acts in the same way

Comment: Think of bubble sort, you only need to provide a function which returns less than `0` if the first is less than the second.

Comment: But it have to return something in the other case! cannot just return NOTHING

Comment: There's no need for the other case.see my update.Just replace `$list[$i] > $list[$i + 1]` with `func($list[$i]) > func($list[$i+1])`

Comment: the > operator return 1 if a > b but return 0 if !(a > b) that is equivalent to a <= b

Comment: Yes,but `func` can be simply `func($a, $b){return $a > $b;}`,why need to care the other 2 cases?

Comment: in fact funct can be like you defined! but func in fact will return 1 if and only if $a > $b and 0 if and only if $a <= $ that is what i wrote in the answer

Comment: Oh you're right,so the document is wrong,it doesn't need to return less than 0,right?

Comment: @lexer: The documentation is correct, in the sense that it's the definition of the interface to this function.  You're free to provide a callback that only provides two return values, but it's not guaranteed to work.